# "This type of file could harm your computer" message in IE9

Tags: php, download, internet-explorer-9, exe

Why if I link directly the *.exe file in the following way:

```
<a href="http://download.domain.com/setup.exe">Download setup</a>
```

I don't get the IE9 message: *"This type of file could harm your computer"*, while with the following PHP file serve approach, the message pops out?

```
header("Content-type:application/octet-stream");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=setup.exe");
readfile("http://download.domain.com/setup.exe");
```

Thanks.

Comment: Maybe because in the first example, the user is currently viewing `blablah.exe` in the URL, while in the latter it may be a form of deceiving users? It's the only reason I can think of.

Answer (score 0):

You should add the following headers:

1. Add the `Content-Length` header information.
2. Set `Content-Transfer-Encoding` to binary.

Also, is the file transferred from a secure url? (https).

Comment: Why should the secure url matter only in PHP file serving?

Comment: I don't think it does, but I could imagine IE whine about serving exe files. If so, an secure url would be more trustworthy. Have you tried the additional headers?

Comment: Yes, now I am even using Content-length header. No improvements.